# Allow only dates from today on in datePicker

Tags: ios, swift

```
@IBAction func dat(sender: UITextField) {


        var datePickerView:UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
        sender.inputView = datePickerView
        datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: Selector("datePickerValueChanged:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

}
func datePickerValueChanged(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    var dateformatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateformatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle
    ld.text = dateformatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
}

@IBAction func ett(sender: UITextField) {
    var datePickerView  : UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Time
    sender.inputView = datePickerView

    et = sender


    datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: "handleDatePicker:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.AllEvents)
```

i want to show only current date  ie like appointment fixing. ineed to show only current date . how to write logic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add This line:

```
datePickerView.minimumDate=NSDate()
```

Hope It Helps....:)